# trimming audio and video with ffmpeg and filter_complex

Tags: ffmpeg

Quick info: Windows 7, latest ffmpeg x64 build

I have multiple segments of video (1080i x264 + ac3 in an mpeg-ts container) that I want to concatenate together.  However, for each segment, I also need to trim x seconds from the beginning of the audio, and add y frames/seconds of blank video to the end of the video.  With this code, I've managed to concatenate a/v and trim the first x seconds of audio for 2 segments:

```
ffmpeg64.exe -y -i "FOLDER\1.ts" -i "FOLDER\2.ts" -filter_complex "[0:v]copy[v0];[0:a]atrim=start=1.245[a0];[1:v]copy[v1];[1:a]atrim=start=1.235[a1];[v0][a0][v1][a1]concat=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -q 0 -c:a ac3 -ab 384k -ac 6 -async 1 "FOLDER\Final.ts" > "FOLDER\log.txt" 2>&1
```

However, I can't seem to add blank frames to the video.  How would I do this?

*the "-q 0" is a temporary placeholder for the actual video encoding, which will be lower bitrate x264.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg64.exe -y -i "FOLDER\1.ts" -i "FOLDER\2.ts" -f lavfi -i color=s=hd1080 -filter_complex "[2]trim=0:y0[tail0];[2]trim=0:y1[tail1];[0:v][tail0]concat[v0];[1:v][tail1]concat[v1];[0:a]atrim=start=1.245[a0];[1:a]atrim=start=1.235[a1];[v0][a0][v1][a1]concat=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -q 0 -c:a ac3 -ab 384k -ac 6 -async 1 "FOLDER\Final.ts" > "FOLDER\log.txt" 2>&1
```

(You don't need the copy filters.)

Comment: Thank you!  It works great.  Can I just ask you to explain what the "trim=0:y0" means exactly?

Comment: It means to trim from `0` seconds to `y0` seconds.

Comment: Right.  That was a dumb question.  Thank you.